# Unable to upgrade mariadb 'You have held broken packages'

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to upgrade from mariadb 10.1 to the newest version (10.5) on Debian 8.11.
Everything fine until :

```
apt-get install mariadb-server
```

And the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.5 (>= 1:10.5.5+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried many things, including the following

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
```

As well as the solution provided [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-deb-files/#version-mismatch-between-mariadb-and-ubuntudebian-repositories)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, this will install MariaDB to the newest version.

```
curl -sS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash
apt update
apt upgrade
apt remove mysql-common
apt install mariadb-server
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I also had problems before where i had to clear out old instances of mysql. Tried updating maria, wouldn't update or install. Thought it was weird. Think it's from an old version hanging up.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mariadb-server* mariadb-client*
```

The Star behind each instance clears all versions it seems a little better. It worked for me with mysql. For Maria didn't work the same. Had to use the below line.

```
curl -sS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install mariadb-server
```